# Event onValueChange on a date. PrimeNG 5.2.4

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am trying to use the event `onValueChange`, according to the PrimeNG documentation, but it does not work.

**View**

```
<p-calendar (onValueChange)="changeFechaFinEstimada()" [(ngModel)]="empleado.fechaFinEstimada" [locale]="es" dateFormat="dd-mm-yy"
                            [showIcon]="true" name="fechaFinEstimada" id="field_caducidad" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true"
                            yearRange="2018:2030"></p-calendar>
```

**Controller**

```
changeFechaFinEstimada() {
    console.log(empleado);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onValueChange` event is not available for PrimeNG 5.2.4. It's only available from *6.0.0-beta.1* as you can see [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5854).

Best way to know if something is available or not is to have a look at the code from the version you use.

[5.2.4](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/5.2.4/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts) => `onValueChange` does not exist

[6.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/6.0.0-beta.1/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts) => `onValueChange` exists

Comment: I'm looking at the link you've put me. But I still do not see if you can or not, make an "onChange" of my date, and if I can, how to do it in version 5.2.4. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can use `onSelect` event.